# Why does my site whitescreen with content?

Tags: 8, debugging, proxies, wsod

I am creating a drupal 8 site.  I have only installed two modules so far, Devel and Varnish.

However anytime I try to create an article and save it any page on the site that isn't an admin page is just White screen of Death.

I have no idea what could be causing this problem.  Why would it cause the white screen?

Comment: Devel is the most up-to-date module for D8 so I think the issue is the Varnish. Look into dblog to see what is causing the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 8 is still in beta so things are still going to be rough there.

WSOD's are usually a symptom of some PHP error being hidden by the web server (many default PHP setups don't advertise errors). The [d.o. page on WSODs](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043) gives good advice on how revealing these errors and diagnosing the problem.

Comment: Thats the answer I was expecting and afraid of. thanks.

Comment: Yeah, moreover the Devel & Varnish projects are still in development w/o stable releases yet. That's likely to be the case until D8 hits a stable release.

Comment: My experience with D8 is that since the APIs are subject to change many modules only work with a limited range of beta versions. If you are not ready to patch contribs to fix such errors D8 is not going to be for you as things stand.

Answer (score 2):

For dev enviroment you can follow the instructions of the [sites/example.settings.local.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/example.settings.local.php?h=8.0.x)

> Local development override configuration feature.
>
> To activate this feature, copy and rename it such that its path plus
>   filename is 'sites/example.com/settings.local.php', where example.com
>   is the name of your site. Then, go to the bottom of
>   'sites/example.com/settings.php' and uncomment the commented lines
>   that mention 'settings.local.php'.

With this you:

- Enable local development services.
- **Show all error messages, with backtrace information.**
- Disable CSS and JS aggregation.
- Disable the render cache (this includes the page cache).
- Allow test modules and themes to be installed.
- Enable access to rebuild.php.

Comment: I dont see any line commented that mentions settings.local.php

Comment: The line comment is in the bottom of you settings.php or search for the string 'settings.local.php' (without quotes), see [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/sites/default/default.settings.php?h=8.0.x#n672).